# Selenium isn't returning current url

Tags: python, selenium

I am setting up a python script to go to a shipping company website and enter a tracking number and get the shipment and delivery dates back and I am having trouble with the selenium current_url method. The code I have opens the initial browser window and enters the tracking number and goes to the shipment status page but I can't find the table item on the resulting page. At first I thought it was the way I was looking for the table item but I discovered that the results page url is still the same as the initial url I started on. I even added an implicit wait time to make sure the page had loaded and still get the same. Here is what my code looks like:

I think there is still an issue with finding the table element on the results page but I can't be sure until I figure out if I am searching the correct url so I need to get past that first. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Max

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = 
webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/USER/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.dovelogistics.com/track-shipment/")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("txtInputNo")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("224893")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

resultsPage = driver.current_url
driver.get(resultsPage)

driver.get("http://206.50.6.81/WebtrakWT/shipinquiry/ShipInfo.aspx? 
 OrderNo=26198&Back=ShipLookup&TrackType=HousebillNo&TrackNo=224893")

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Table5']")
print (elem)

driver.close()
```

Comment: can you remove the extra code and leave an example that shows exactly what you are seeing.  your question is also very unclear.

Comment: you also have line breaks that make the code unrunnable as-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That website opens another window. You have to switch to that window. And they are using table id tags more than once. This should help:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.dovelogistics.com/track-shipment/')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("txtInputNo")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("224893")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)

elem = driver.find_elements_by_id("Table1")
print (elem)

driver.close()
```

You have to cope with their nested tables and duplicate id tags.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try that. I didn't know there was a need to switch windows.

Answer (score 2):

You should accept Jens Dibbern solution, but just wanted to point out you could also used pandas to pull that table to parse once you get your url to pass in:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.dovelogistics.com/track-shipment/")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("txtInputNo")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("224893")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
resultsPage = driver.current_url
driver.get(resultsPage)

html = driver.page_source

tables = pd.read_html(html)
table = tables[5]

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (table)
                        0                                                  1
0       Status Updated On                                               Note
1    12/4/2018 1:07:00 PM                  Shipment Status changed to: Rated
2    12/4/2018 1:07:00 PM  Signed for By: Delivered at KWA 1:07:00 PM 12/...
3    12/4/2018 9:37:43 AM                     Email Status Notification Sent
4   12/2/2018 11:50:00 AM      Shipment Status changed to: Shipment Departed
5    12/1/2018 2:12:00 PM       Shipment Status changed to: Shipment Arrived
6   12/1/2018 10:39:00 AM      Shipment Status changed to: Shipment Departed
7    12/1/2018 9:28:00 AM       Shipment Status changed to: Shipment Arrived
8   11/30/2018 2:53:55 PM  Shipment Status changed to: Shipment Departed ...
9   11/28/2018 8:42:23 PM  Shipment Status changed to: On-Hand At Origin ...
10  11/28/2018 5:53:47 PM  Shipment Status changed to: Dispatched for Pickup
```

Comment: Awesome thanks very much. That will help me in the next step!